# Find the set $\{a^n\,|\,n\geq1\}$ which $F$ is a field of order 32 and $a\in F$ that is not zero and one of the field

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of order 32. $0_F\neq a\in F$ and $a\neq1_F$. What is the set $\{a^n\,|\,n\geq1\}$?

I started by saying that $|F|=32=2^5$. Hence, $\text{char}(F)=2$ and obviously $\forall{a}\in F, a+a=0_F$. After this, I don't know how to continue to find that set. I heared that the answer is the set $F\setminus\{0_F\}$ that is of order 31 (I don't know if it's correct or not). But I don't know how to show that. I also considered that finite fields of the same order are isomorphic. Any help is so musch appreciated!

**Note.** Please consider that I recently started studying linear algebra. I'm reading *K. Hoffman* and *R. Kunze* book. I haven't studied abstract algebra and I don't know about rings, groups, group extensions, etc. I appreciate paying attention to this and giving any help that uses only field axioms, field properties, field characteristic and so on.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783878/find-this-set-that-its-elements-are-a-natural-power-of-elements-of-a-field)

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the body. (In the title, $a$ varies; in the body $a$ is fixed)

Comment: @Magdiragdag I think in both $a$ varies. The question in the body is how I saw it and I thought it means $a$ varies. If $a$ is fixed, do we get 31 as answer?

Comment: If $a$ varies $\{a^n \mid a \in F\setminus\{0,1\}, n \geq 1\}$, then the question is more reading comprehension than algebra; if $a$ is fixed,  then it's the same question as linked by @J.W.Tanner.